# How can I call a MySQL stored function from Java?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-functions

I have the [Sakila Sample Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) in my local, and I am trying to call the [get_customer_balance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-functions-get_customer_balance.html) Function from Java.

This is the code I have:

```
double callableStatementFunctionCallExample(final int customerId) throws SQLException {
    double customerBalance = -1;

    final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

    final CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL ? = get_customer_balance(?, ?)}");
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, customerBalance);
    callableStatement.setInt(2, customerId);
    final java.sql.Date date = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    callableStatement.setDate(3, date);

    callableStatement.execute();
    return customerBalance;
}
```

which results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter.
```

So I replaced this statement..

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, customerBalance);
```

with..

```
callableStatement.setDouble(1, customerBalance);
```

which results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter p_film_count is not registered as an output parameter.
```

So obviously I need to register an `out parameter`, but how? Why is my first approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature of method is [`void registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, int sqlType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter-int-int-), where `sqlType` is described as "the JDBC type code defined by `java.sql.Types`".

That means your call should be:

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DOUBLE);
```

And you retrieve that value after the `execute()` call using:

```
double customerBalance = callableStatement.getDouble(1);
```

You were calling it with value `-1`, which is the value of `Types.LONGVARCHAR`.

---

Also, javadoc of [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) shows that the syntax of the SQL string is `{?= call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}`, which means your statement should be:

```
final CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{? = CALL get_customer_balance(?, ?)}");
```

---

Both problems could have been fixed if you'd read the javadoc.

Comment: Still getting: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter.

Answer (score 0):

before execute() register by type (e.g. integer):

```
final CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call get_customer_balance(?, ?)}");

callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: Still getting: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter